# How do I set the Ruby test/unit logging to quiet_mode?

Tags: ruby, logging, testunit

I'm trying to set the logging level for the tests I'm running in test/unit

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'logger'
class MyMath
  def self.adder(a,b)
    a+b
  end
end

class Tester < Test::Unit::TestCase
  $logger = Logger.new($stdout)
  def test_adder()
    $logger.info "Starting Test"
    assert_equal(4, MyMath.adder(2,2) )
    $logger.info "Ending   Test"
  end
end
```

And the output is

```
Loaded suite ruby.test
Started
I, [2021-07-23T13:12:26.497311 #49542]  INFO -- : Starting Test
I, [2021-07-23T13:12:26.497375 #49542]  INFO -- : Ending   Test
.
Finished in 0.000358 seconds.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2793.30 tests/s, 2793.30 assertions/s
```

How do I get it to NOT print the logging messages?  In the Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner code it talks about

```
      # Creates a new TestRunner for running the passed
      # suite. If quiet_mode is true, the output while
      # running is limited to progress dots, errors and
      # failures, and the final result. io specifies
      # where runner output should go to; defaults to
      # STDOUT.
```

What is quiet_mode, and how can I set it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you need to set the log level of your logger accordingly.

```
$logger = Logger.new($stdout)
$logger.level = Logger::WARN
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html

Not sure if you use any framework so you could just set the log level in test like

```rb
if ENV["test"]
  $logger.level = Logger::WARN
end
```